# Single query to get count of individual of past 7 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I do know that the following conditions will return the total number in the past 7 days

```
SELECT count(id) FROM registration 
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

Is there a single query that I can do to get the past 7 days returning in an array of 7 results of each individual day?

For example:

```
day 1 - 10
day 2 - 5
day 3 - 9
..
..
..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you the date and the count.

```
SELECT DATE(createdDate),COUNT(id)
FROM registration
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY DATE(createdDate)
```

Alternatively to give a result closer to your example you could use:

```
SELECT CONCAT("Day ",DATEDIFF(NOW(), createdDate)) AS day,COUNT(id)
FROM registration
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY DATE(createdDate)
```

Comment: wow thats great, do you reckon its possible to show a 0 count if there are no registration on a particular day?

day 1 - 4
day 2 - 3
day 3 - 0
day 4 - 1
day 5 - 0

something like that

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to display a 0 for no registrations with the above query. You could either do that in the PHP side or use something like @Barmar's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Add a group-by clause:

```
SELECT count(id), DATE(createdDate)
FROM registration
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY DATE(createdDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 8 - n day, count(id)
from registration
join (select 1 n union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7) x
on createdDate between date_sub(curdate(), interval n day) and date_sub(curdate(), interval n-1 day)
group by day
order by day
```